# google analyics Javascript ssl version

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, google-analytics, firebug

I just noticed in Firebug that the ssl version of the ga.js file appears to be  smaller than the normal version. 
I was wonder could someone explain this to me.

and if it is smaller why don't people just use the ssl version?

https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js

https://google-analytics.com/ga.js

Answer (score 1):

md5 says they're identical:

```
$ curl https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js | md5sum
e9403bf7353597ac42458d43d2017e24

$ curl http://google-analytics.com/ga.js | md5sum
e9403bf7353597ac42458d43d2017e24
```

Comment: Yeah thanks . but still the firebug network traffic tab. shows the ssl one as smaller?

Comment: That points to a bug in Firefox as they're identical size and content on disk. Regardless, the https version should, I believe, actually have a slightly higher weight due to http overhead/footprint anyway

Comment: You might be looking at the size of the HTTP request not the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS requires an initial handshake : this round trip can be slow, and the amount of data transferred is not negligible.

In GA case, the ssl handshake take approximately 110ms from my place and is 2594 bytes. Nearly 18% of the script size !

In conclusion : the HTTPS request/response is bigger.

Comment: Most modern browsers shouldn't need to do the handshake anymore as these are cached. OP states that the SSL version is smaller, which I don't get.